# Meaning of 'to (not) burn old women as witches'

Tags: meaning

In this sentence from Bertrand Russell,

> At one time—not so very long ago—it was considered monstrous wickedness to maintain that old women ought not to be burnt as witches.

which one is the bygone belief that Russell is expressing?

1. All old women must be burnt because they're witches.
2. Those old women who are witches must be burnt.

To me, the second sounds (slightly) more rational, while the structure of Russell's sentence suggests the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bygone belief was:

> If an old woman is a witch, then she should be burnt accordingly.

Looking at more of the sentence, we see that Russell is trying to say:

> There was a time — not so very long ago — when, if you didn't believe a witch should be burned, you were regarded as monstrously wicked.

I can see why you have trouble picking up the second meaning from the structure of the original; it's because Russell is leaving out a tidbit that is implied:

> ...it was considered monstrous wickedness to maintain that old women [*who are presumed to be witches*] ought not to be burnt as witches.

Without this implied information, the sentence might sound like it applies to all old women, but that is not the case. Russell is relying on the reader to know he is referring to women who were thought to be witches.

Answer (score 0):

Not long ago  to **opine** (to "maintain") that old women should not be burned as witches was considered wicked.

The opinion was considered wicked.

It may be reasonable to understand **old women** to mean "those of them thought to be witches" but there's no basis in the statement *itself* for making that assumption.  It is only from *context* that we can make that assumption.

Russell's remark is an offhand **allusion** to an historical context: women young and old were burnt as witches. The allusion is not unlike

> Some people consider it a mercy to euthanize *those in great pain*.

We can only *presume* the speaker means "who are suffering from a terminal illness" as the statement appears to be an allusion to that debate.

It is misguided to treat offhand allusions as rigorous propositions. They need to be understood in the context of what they're alluding to.

Comment: Good analogy. I wouldn't want to be euthanized the next time I stubbed my toe – no matter how much it might hurt in the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Russel is saying that to hold the opinion that witches should not be burned was an extremely unpopular one. You see Russel is commenting on the opinion of burning witches and not about which old women should be roasted.